# How to access the drag drop event of outlook 2007 inbox in outlook VSTO add in?

Tags: email, drag-and-drop, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an outlook VSTO add in.I have a tree view in a custom task pane.What I want to do is that when a user drag drops a tree node on to the inbox,it should create a new email,download the file based upon the data in drag drop events and attach the file to the email.But I am unable to figure out any drag drop event for outlook's inbox.Where can I find it?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only drag/drop operations that are supported are the Explorer.BeforeItemCopy/Cut/Paste events, but that only handles Outlook items that are copied or moved from one folder to another and not Windows Form controls.

Otherwise everything else is possible, but tricky and not supported.  See here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/04/01/drag-and-drop-with-outlook.aspx

Comment: Thanx for the help.I knew this bit already, that I can pass a file path during doDragDrop . But, I wanted control of the drag drop event of inbox, which is not possible as mentioned in the link.